# getting shell command from user input and executing C program

Tags: c, linux, fork, execvp

currently working on program which recieves input command for linux shell and executing them creating child process.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
  int pid, status;
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s command, [arg1 [arg2]...]\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  printf("Starting %s...\n", argv[1]);
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    perror("execvp");
    return EXIT_FAILURE; // Never get there normally
  } else {
    if (wait(&status) == -1) {
      perror("wait");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Works with input like `./program command arg` but needed to receive various commands with args for example : `./program command arg command arg .....`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually say what your problem is, but my guess is that you are having problems working out how each forked process will consume the parameters.

I guess what you do is that each time you fork you need to advance the `argv` pointer to the next command/arg pair.  This forking loop terminates when the command is the zero terminator.

I hope I have understood your question because you haven't actually stated what aspect of this problem you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

`argc` tells you the size of `argv`

You'd need to extract them from `argv` using that info.

Note that this doesn't solve the problem of commands with different numbers of args.

**Edit for that reason in reply to comments:**

You can look at `getopt()` which would allow you to do this:

```
 ./program -c "command arg1 arg2" -c "command arg1" ...
```

The problem is you need to be able to differentiate between your command/arg sets. `getopt()` would at least get you half way there, then you just need to parse each set. Though it's really overkill since that's your only input type. Iterating through `argv` would be just as easy in this case.

Another option would be to separate them with a delimiter:

```
./program command arg1, command arg1 arg2, ...
```

You'd need to iterate through `argv` and look for the comma to know a command/arg set was complete. Or concat all of argv into a string and use `strtok()`. Kinda ugly IMHO but doable.

Comment: but i want to let user to use arbitrary number of commands with arguments, of course i will have to change that if(argc > 2) but don't know how to deal with that without knowing the number of commands that user wants to input.

Comment: You either need to pass them in as single, quoted arguments (e.g. `./program "command arg arg" "command2 arg arg"`) and then parse each string, or come up with a delimiter that lets you know when one command/arg set is complete (and iterate through `argv`)

Comment: Actually ... you *may* be able to do this with getopt(), it's been a while ... looking

Answer (score 0):

A shell is a complex piece of software, I recently had to implement one for an Operating Systems class and it was difficult; and we only had to control one command per input (though we did also have to implement I/O redirection, and piping, and had to do path searching manually then execute with `execv()`).

The problem you are going to have lies in that there really isn't any way to tell if the next arg string in the array of command line parameters is a command or argument to a previous command. The only ways that you can differentiate commands and their args is if you **know** that it will alternate `command arg command arg ...`, or have some other standardized number of arguments per command (which isn't very useful) or have a deliminator between commands like a semicolon: `command arg; command arg arg arg; ...`

In the case that you **know** it will alternate then you can just loop through the args like so:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i += 2)
{
   //command is argv[i], arg is argv[i + 1]
}
```

A better way to do this, would be instead of using command line parameters create an input prompt then process one command per line, just like normal shell usage.

Comment: well i have other way to handle it with while, something like :  ` while (1) {    
          printf("Shell -> ");   
          gets(line);            
          printf("\n");
          parse(line, argv);    
          if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0) 
               exit(0);         
          execute(argv);
     } ` but this way it will looks like a shell but i pretend to make that user can execute various commands with args in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question here is parsing argv.

Here is a dummy logical flow:

```
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        isCommand = CheckCmd(argv[i]);  /* check if argv[i] is a command */
        if (isCommand)
        {
            for(; i < argc; i++)
            {
                isCommand = CheckCmd(argv[i]);  /* check if argv[i] is a command */
                if (isNotCommand)
                {
                    PushOption(argv[i]); /* save options */
                } else
                {
                    /* Get Command and options from stack */
                    /* execute command with fork/execv */
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

The only thing you need here is to realize CheckCmd and PushOption/PopOption.